# Инкапсуляция Java смена переменной через сеттер происходит после выполнения кода с ней(этой переменной)

Tags: java

/*
За каждый месяц банк начисляет к сумме вклада 7% от суммы. Напишите консольную программу,
в которую пользователь вводит сумму вклада и количество месяцев. А банк вычисляет конечную сумму вклада с
учетом начисления процентов за каждый месяц.
*/
вывод в консоль при 100 на 1 будет 107.0outputmoney и 0.1 вместо  110 и 0.1 помогите пожалуйста

```
class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person  person = new Person();
    person.setProcent(0.1);

    System.out.println(person.getProccent());

    }
}

class Person{
    private static double proccent = 0.07;
 public  Person(){

 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter how mutsh  money you wont too depoosit");
  float money = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter how many time(mounth) this money will in bank");
 int time = in.nextInt();
 float outputmoney =0;
     for (int i = 0; i <time; i++) {
         money += money * proccent;
     }
     System.out.println(money +"outputmoney");
 }
    public void setProcent(double proccent){
        this.proccent = proccent;
    }
    public double getProccent(){
        return proccent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вас не устраивает в outpute? Не совсем понятно ваше последнее предложение. Вам нужно что бы на выходе было 110 .... 0.1 или 107....0.07?

Comment: Я б сказал вообще не понятно.  Нормально сформулируйте вопрос

Comment: 100 на 1 месяц под 10 %, получается 110, что не так?

Comment: прошу прощение за формулировку  вообщем да я через сеттер хочу изменить приватную переменную проценты и чтобы код выполнялся уже с изменённой переменной , а выходит так что он(код) берет староее значение 7 процентов  и не изменяет на 10 и вывод 107 а не 110(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы поместили код в конструктор, а не в метод. Соответственно он выполняется до того, как вы измените переменную процента. То есть вы сначала выполняете всю логику, а только ПОСЛЕ ЭТОГО меняете процент. Потому что код в конструкторе выполняется в тот момент, когда вы прописываете **new** в main Вынесите логику в отдельный метод, и вызывайте его уже после изменения процента. Выглядить это будет примерно так:

```
public class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person  person = new Person();
        person.setProcent(0.1);
        person.deposit();

        System.out.println(person.getProccent());

    }
}

class Person{
    private static double proccent = 0.07;
    public  Person(){


    }
    public void setProcent(double proccent){
        this.proccent = proccent;
    }
    public double getProccent(){
        return proccent;
    }

    public void deposit(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter how mutsh  money you wont too depoosit");
        float money = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter how many time(mounth) this money will in bank");
        int time = in.nextInt();
        float outputmoney =0;
        for (int i = 0; i <time; i++) {
            money += money * proccent;
        }
        System.out.println(money +" outputmoney");
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
Enter how mutsh  money you wont too depoosit
100
Enter how many time(mounth) this money will in bank
1
110.0 outputmoney
0.1
```

Comment: Вы что тут 24 на 7 дежурите?:)

Comment: @ScruffytheJanitor  ага, на зарплате =)

Comment: спасибо вам огромное had0uken и Scruffy the Janitor

Comment: @Andrii Kravchenko Чтоб поблагодарить выберите ответ правильным, баллы дадут. Вам had0uken детально все расписал , можете его ответ выбрать

Answer (score 1):

У вас реализация вся в конструкторе. Тоесть при создании объекта   посути выполнился весь расчет с 7% , а потом после того как основная логика программы уже закончилась и получился расчёт,  вы меняете в экземпляре процент.  Выносите расчет за конструктор в отдельный метод  либо в самом конструкторе сделайте возможность задавать процент как вы это делаете с месяцами и суммой